# How to Draw Correct Sign using PaperJs?

Tags: html, paperjs

[Correct Sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MnYY.png)

I want to draw something like above using PaperJs on image converted to Canvas, can someone point me to right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the [nice tutorials](http://paperjs.org/tutorials/), especially the [ones about paths](http://paperjs.org/tutorials/paths/working-with-path-items/).

```js
 paper.install(window);
 window.onload = function() {
  paper.setup('myCanvas');
        var myPath = new Path();
        myPath.strokeColor = 'black';
        myPath.add(new Point(0, 0));
        myPath.add(new Point(100, 50));
      myPath.lastSegment.handleIn = new Point(50,80);
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.10.2/paper-core.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```